# Javascript file messes with scrollbar in PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My `test2.php` looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
...
...
...


//A lot of other scripts aswell
<script src="assets/js/custom.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html
```

The scrollbar is there for a millisec until the script custom.min.js has been loaded. Inside that script, a custom scroll is created. The custom scrolls isn't visible and isn't working since I've switched from .html to .php and I just want to remove it and keep the normal scrollbar in my .php file but the javascript file has somehow deleted the functionality for the default scroll behaviour, making me unsure of how to tackle the issue. What I want is to remove the code about the custom scroll but I can't seem to find it, The code is here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/08ab6aa4f362490eb591fec1fb1d363b

Here is some information about the scroll created in the .php file and how the html code looks like: 
[image: custom scroll in html]

I just want this custom scroll removed, and want the normal scroll back with the default functions as this one "crashes" the scrollbar functionality

Comment: Scrollbars are a browser feature and have nothing to do with PHP. You've probably just broken your layout when you've added PHP to it. First of all validate your HTML to make sure it's not broken (https://validator.w3.org/) and then check the console for any JavaScript errors which may be a result of badly formatted tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `<!doctype html>` to the start of the .php file fixed everything. That was the issue.. I'm sorry for disappointing you Stackoverflow.